# Is it possible to connect two Skype for Business instances (distinct companies)?

Tags: skype, skype-for-business-2016

My company has a very restrictive policy regarding IT security; most cloud solutions are forbidden. We have an on-premises Skype for Business instance.

In one of our projects, involving only a small subset of the company employees, we work with some partner companies which have Skype for Business too.

For improved collaboration, we'd like to be able to chat over Skype with the employees there.

Is there a known way to achieve this? Microsoft Documentation is not telling much. I don't ask for precise configuration instructions, but for the shared experience of the community at the concept level.

Restriction: the partner company shall only have access to our project team, not to the entire company's employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keywords you should be looking for are (`Skype for Business` OR `Lync`) AND `federation`. See https://www.petri.com/setup-lync-federation for an overview.

Comment: Clearly that was the answer I expected. So amazingly fast. Thank you ServerFault community.